# Java program to find the letter that appears in the most words?

Tags: java

I have a sentence, and I want to find the char that appears in the most words, and how many words it appears in.
For example: "I like visiting my friend Will, who lives in Orlando, Florida."
             Which should output `I 8`.
This is my code:

```
        char maxChar2 = '\0';
        int maxCount2 = 1;
        for (int j=0; j<strs2.length; j++) {
        int charCount = 1;
        char localChar = '\0';
        for (int k=0; k<strs2[j].length(); k++) {
            if (strs2[j].charAt(k) != ' ' && strs2[j].charAt(k) != maxChar2) {
                for (int l=k+1; l<strs2[j].length(); l++) {    
                    if (strs2[j].charAt(k)==strs2[j].charAt(l)) {
                        localChar = strs2[j].charAt(k);
                        charCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (charCount > maxCount2) {
            maxCount2 = charCount;
            maxChar2 = localChar;
        }
    }
```

, where strs2 is a String array.
My program is giving me `O 79`. Also, uppercase and lowercase do not matter and avoid all punctuation.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Output should be `I 8`, not `I 7`. There are 8 words with `I` in them: **I**, l**i**ke, v**i**siting, fr**i**end, W**i**ll, l**i**ves, **i**n, Flor**i**da. As proven by this code: [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Tqpgz1)

Comment: If input is the text `I like visiting my friend Will, who lives in Orlando, Florida.`, then what is the String *array* `strs2`? The text is just a *single* string, not an array of strings.

Comment: @Andreas - strs2 is a String array of the words. For example, it has "I", "like", "visiting", etc. Also: thanks for noticing the error in my example.

Comment: @JohnDoe Your currently accepted [answer by RAZ_Muh_Taz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41684742/5221149) produces the [wrong result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682904/java-program-to-find-the-letter-that-appears-in-the-most-words/41683717?noredirect=1#comment70568276_41684742), and the algorithm cannot be adjusted to produce the right result. An entirely different algorithm is needed, so you might want to reconsider accepting that answer, since it'll mislead others searching for a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a tip, try using more meaningful variable names and proper indentation. This will help a lot especially when your program is not doing what you thought it should do. Also starting smaller and writing some tests for it will help a bunch. Instead of a full sentence, get it working for 2 words, then 3 words, then a more elaborate sentence.

Rewriting your code to be a bit more readable:

```
// Where sentence is: "I like".split(" ");
private static void getMostFrequentLetter(String[] sentence) {
    char mostFrequentLetter = '\0';
    int mostFrequentLetterCount = 1;

    for (String word : sentence) {
        int charCount = 1;
        char localChar = '\0';

        for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < word.length(); wordIndex++) {
            char currentLetter = word.charAt(wordIndex);

            if (currentLetter != ' ' && currentLetter != mostFrequentLetter) {
                for (int l = wordIndex + 1; l < word.length(); l++) {
                    char nextLetter = word.charAt(l);

                    if (currentLetter == nextLetter) {
                        localChar = currentLetter;
                        charCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (charCount > mostFrequentLetterCount) {
            mostFrequentLetterCount = charCount;
            mostFrequentLetter = localChar;
        }
    }
}
```

Now all I did was rename your variables and change your for loop to a for-each loop. By doing this you can see more clearly your algorithm and what you're trying to do. Basically you're going through each word and comparing the current letter with the next letter to check for duplicates. If I run this with "I like" i should get `i 2` but instead I get `null char 1`. You aren't properly comparing and saving common letters. This isn't giving you the answer, but I hope this makes it more clear what your code is doing so you can fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a somewhat more elegant solution

```
public static void FindMostPopularCharacter(String input)
{
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    input = input.toUpperCase();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> charData = new HashMap<>();
    char occursTheMost = 'A'; //start with default most popular char
    int maxCount = 0;

    //create the map to store counts of all the chars seen
    for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++)
        charData.put(alphabet.charAt(i), 0);


    //first find the character to look for
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        //if contained in our map increment its count
        if(charData.containsKey(c))
            charData.put(c, charData.get(c) + 1);
        //check for a max count and set the values accordingly
        if(charData.containsKey(c) && charData.get(c) > maxCount)
        {
            occursTheMost = c;
            maxCount = charData.get(c);
        }
    }
    //final step
    //now split it up into words and search which contain our most popular character
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    int wordCount = 0;
    CharSequence charSequence;
    for(Character character : charData.keySet())
    {
        int tempCount = 0;
        charSequence = "" + character;
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            if(words[i].contains(charSequence))
                tempCount++;
        }

        if(tempCount > wordCount)
        {
            occursTheMost = character;
            wordCount = tempCount;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(occursTheMost + " " + wordCount);
}
```

Output of

```
String input = "I like visiting my friend Will, who lives in Orlando, Florida.";
FindMostPopularCharacter(input);
```

is

```
I 8
```

Note: If there are ties this will only output the character that first reaches the maximum number of occurrences.

```
FindMostPopularCharacter("aabb aabb aabb bbaa");
```

Outputs

```
B 4
```

because B reaches the max first before A due to the last word in the input.

```
FindMostPopularCharacter("aab aab b")

B 3
```

Comment: Incorrect result. `FindMostPopularCharacter("aab aab b")` prints `A 2`, but answer is `B 3`. Your entire premise is that most occurring letter also occurs in the most words. That is hereby proven to be a false assumption, and hence the code fails to produce the right result.

Comment: @Andreas good catch, i misunderstood and thought he only wanted to find which character was found the most in the sentence and how many words it is found in.